# How do i normalize my data that is in one dataframe to the mean value of a different parameter in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I am just a beginner so i will explain this the best I can.

I have one dataframe which contains

| sample name | fano factor |
| --- | --- |
| A1 (old) | 10 |
| A2 (old) | 9 |

the other data frame consist out of the following

| sample name | fano factor |
| --- | --- |
| A1 (new) | 9 |
| A2 (new) | 7 |

How do i normalize my "new" A values to the old A values?

I don't really know where to start since i only know how to normalize within one dataframe

Comment: what is the expected output? Are the difference in names literally `(old)`/`(new)`?

Answer (score 1):

The expected output is unclear, but it looks like you want to align the two DataFrames. For this, you can [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) the `(old)` by `(new)` and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values:

```
s = (df_old['fano factor']
     .set_axis(df_old['sample name'].str.replace('(old)', '(new)', regex=False))
     )

# example operation, you can do anything you want
df_new['ratio'] = df_new['fano factor']/df_new['sample name'].map(s)
```

Output:

```
  sample name  fano factor     ratio
0    A1 (new)            9  0.900000
1    A2 (new)            7  0.777778
```